# how to prevent duplicate entry in table?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, unique-constraint

i have 1 table:

table1:

`used_tag_id | post_id | tag_id`

`user_tag_id` is the primary key.

There is multiple entries for `post_id` and `tag_id`.

if i add `post_id`=1 and `tag_id`=1 it should add one time then if again i add `post_id`=1 and `tag_id`=1 then it should not add again into the table.
How to do that?
should i do this with query or is there any way too do it while designing table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

create a compound column `UNIQUE` constraint on the table, eg

```
ALTER TABLE tableName ADD CONSTRAINT tb_uq UNIQUE (post_id, tag_id)
```

Comment: I Can't do that because 1 post_id can have multiple tag_id

Comment: @HarjeetJadeja yes you can. This will allow multiple `tag_id` for every `post_id`. try it.

Comment: if you have executed the alter table statement, these records are still allowed `used_tag_id, post_id, tag_id`, `1,1,1`,`2,1,2`,`3,1,3`,`4,1,4` but not this if you add again `5,1,4`

Comment: suppose i want to remove the uniqueness in future then how to do that?

Comment: `ALTER TABLE tablename DROP CONSTRAINT tb_uq`

Answer (score 0):

1. You can create a Primary key of combination used_tag_id | post_id | tag_id
2. You can check the data by your code before inserting it.

Comment: I have created normal primary key with auto-increment, but how to create primary key of combination?

Comment: CREATE TABLE INFO (
    t1ID INT,
    t2ID INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (t1ID, t2ID)
)

Comment: ya codeing thing is ok. But I don't want to relay on code I want to done it by database itself.

Comment: A composite primary key containing user_tag_id won't achieve what the OP wants, since user_tag_id itself is unique.